# Use equivalence properties to show that $[\neg(p\leftrightarrow q)] \iff [(p\leftrightarrow (\neg q))]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've really been struggling to get the correct answer on this one. I've tried several ways but this is best I've been able to get it down to so far:

$[\neg(p\leftrightarrow q)] \iff [(p\leftrightarrow (\neg q))]$

(i)$[\neg(p\leftrightarrow q)]\iff \neg[(p\to q)\land (q\to p)]$

(ii)$[\neg(p\leftrightarrow q)]\iff \neg(p\to q) \lor \neg(\neg q\lor p)$

(iii)$[\neg(p\leftrightarrow q)]\iff ((p\land \neg q)\lor q) \land p$

(iv)$(q\lor p) \land (q\lor \neg q) \land \neg p$

$q \lor p \land \neg p \land$ **0**

Note: **0** means contradiction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is the following:

$$\neg(p\leftrightarrow q)\leftrightarrow(p\leftrightarrow\neg q)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow\Big(\neg(p\leftrightarrow q)\land(p\leftrightarrow\neg q)\Big)\lor\Big((p\leftrightarrow q)\land\neg(p\leftrightarrow\neg q)\Big)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow\bigg(\Big(\neg p\land q)\lor(p\land\neg q)\Big)\land\Big((p\land\neg q)\lor(\neg p\land q)\Big)\bigg)\lor\bigg(\Big((\neg p\land\neg q)\lor(p\land q)\Big)\land\Big((\neg p\land\neg q)\lor(p\land q)\Big)\bigg)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\land q)\lor(p\land \neg q)\lor(\neg p\land\neg q)\lor(p\land q)$$

First, notice that to go from the second $\Longleftrightarrow$ to the third, we've contracted the conjunctions - since $(A\land A)\leftrightarrow A$.

Now, we're left with the last line, which is essentially a disjunction of all possible truth values assigned to $p$ and $q$ - take a moment to convince yourself that it is indeed the case. Therefore, since we've exhausted all possible cases, the proposition will always be true, i.e. we have shown that $\neg(p\leftrightarrow q)$ and $(p\leftrightarrow\neg q)$ are equivalent.

Finally, you may also want to try the following technique: start by negating the statement you wish to prove is a tautology, and work you way down to the truth values of each sentence letter (either by truth tables or tableaux); if the negated proposition can never be true (i.e. if it is a logical falsehood), then by negation your original proposition must be always true (i.e. a tautology).

---

**EDIT**: after paying more attention to your question, I'll give you an answer that might be more along the lines of what you first tried to do.

\begin{align}\neg(p\leftrightarrow q)\Longleftrightarrow&\neg\big((p\to q)\land(q\to p)\big)\\\Longleftrightarrow&\neg(p\to q)\lor\neg(q\to p)\\\Longleftrightarrow&(p\land\neg q)\lor(q\land\neg p)\\\Longleftrightarrow&(p\leftrightarrow\neg q)\end{align}

where to move from the penultimate to the last line, we have simply used the definition of the biconditional ("equivalence").

Comment: Now we wait for @Mauro ALLEGRANZA... :)

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe it was so simple. I think I tried to do too much work. I appreciate that you answered this two different ways.